# Md-menu doesn't position properly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

The menu content is partly hidden instead of positioning properly.

```
<md-menu>
    <md-button ng-click="$mdMenu.open($event)">
    <div layout="row"><div>Edit</div><md-icon md-menu-origin>more_vert</md-icon></div>
    </md-button>
    <md-menu-content>
        <md-menu-item>
            <md-button>Save</md-button>
        </md-menu-item>
        <md-menu-item>
           <md-button>Delete</md-button>
        </md-menu-item>
        <md-menu-item>
           <md-button>Print</md-button>
        </md-menu-item>
     </md-menu-content>
  </md-menu>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an screen shot? Because that code looks like it should work. Otherwise try using the property width: `<md-menu-content width="4">`

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion didn't help. The same issue. The screen shop is added. You can see that only the "Save" option is visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I see your view, the problem is not the code, the template is ok, the problem is that you are adding this menu in the bottom of the page, and not using the [offset option](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/menu#menu-position-modes) to correct the position of it, try different values for the `y` axis.

```
<md-menu md-offset="0 -100">
```